# Magento sets zero quantity importing csv with only _links_* column

Tags: product, import, csv, importexport, ce-1.6.2.0

I'm trying to update products adding related, cross sell and `upsell` products by importing a `CSV` from `System->Import/Export->Import functionality`.

After the import process all the modified products (the ones in column "sku") have Quantity set to 0 (zero) and Stock Availability set to **Not in stock**.

**My configuration**

I'm working on `Magento 1.6.2.0`

My CSV file has the following columns:

```
 sku
_links_related_sku
_links_related_position
_links_crosssell_sku
_links_crosssell_position
_links_upsell_sku
_links_upsell_position
```

I don't need and I can't add the **qty** column.

I try both `Append complex data` and `Replace existing Complex Data`.

**My questions**

- Updating product via CSV import there are some required columns as well as `sku`??
- Is there a bug on Magento import system?

**NOTE:**
Time ago, for other stores, a fight with a similar issue importing product programmatically: all imported products gets the quantity specified for the first product and I resolved following the instruction at this link
http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewreply/408209/

But now I'm updating products (and not importing) and this method does not resolve the issue.

Some help?
Thaks

Answer (score 1):

Looks like a bug in that magento version.

You should try updating to a newer version - I couldn't reproduce that behavior in Magento 1.7.0.2. 1.6 is very old and has security problems.